# How to get lattitude and Longitude with only GPS

Tags: android, android-gps

How to get the Location only through GPS without any kind of Internet connection. I use the below code to get the location but not working without the internet. Please let me know why I'm not getting the location without internet

```
        boolean isGPSEnabled = manager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       boolean isNetworkEnabled = manager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                }
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (manager != null) {
                    location = manager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (manager != null) {
                        location = manager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: "+currentLatitude+"   "+currentLongitude);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Above code should work. You need to go outdoors for GPS to post location updates and work.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me the reason why GPS not working indoors?

Comment: Because GPS works through Satellites. You need to be in clear vision of Sky to get the GPS Satellite signals. more info - https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/travel/gps.htm/printable

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the code scope you pasted is famous, it's combination of last known locations of network and GPS providers. Even `getLastKnownLocation`methods are called just after `requestLocationUpdates` methods, this usage is fully not trusted. Because those sensors won't give result in sync way.

You have two options, one is to call `getLastKnownLocation` to get last obtained location for GPS, and second is to make location request with `requestLocationUpdates`. Choosing this, will be determined by your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this short code to get lattitude and Longitude with only GPS**

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("Location = ","Longitude "+location.getLongitude()+",Latitude "+location.getLatitude());
```